# Drools Decision Tables

Tags: drools

I have created a Decision Table, but I keep on getting this error.

> Data cell C11 has an empty column header

My xls DT.

[image: My xls DT]

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Section 6.5.4, Spreadsheet Syntax, of the Drools Manual very carefully. Below `RuleTable` you need four (4) rows: one row with headers like `CONDITION`; below that one cell with a pattern; below that one cell for the constraint expression and then one row for a comment cell.

You have five rows.

To combine two or more patterns, use two or more columns. See the examples in that section.

**Edit** Code to compile a spreadsheet and display the generated DRL:

```
private void testSpreadsheet( String dtPath ){
  File dtf = new File( dtPath );
  InputStream is;
  try {
    is = new FileInputStream( dtf );
    SpreadsheetCompiler ssComp = new SpreadsheetCompiler();
    String s = ssComp.compile( is, InputType.XLS );
    System.out.println( "=== Begin generated DRL ===" );
    System.out.println( s );
    System.out.println( "=== End generated DRL ===" );
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: leune, regarding row 10 org_co == $param, I keep getting mismatched input '==' in rule "Section 01". What does it mean?

Comment: Which cell remained in row 8? Does the class have a field `org_co`?

Comment: The class does have a property org_co

Comment: it would be useful to see the rules that have been generated by Drools at run-time, I don't know how to see them but there must be a way .. ANy help on that?

Comment: Some old code I have lying around, added it to my answer.